# I have problems when loading the website, does it take a long time to load?

Tags: php, wordpress, frontend

I am working on this website, when you load the page it shows a lot in displaying the content is there any way to do it faster?

PHP version 7.2.

Wordpress version 5.3.2.

Comment: This is off topic for Stack Overflow, which is designed for specific programming questions. That said, WordPress has tons of performance and caching plugins available. Some of them can scan your site for pain points and offer suggestions for speeding things up. Good luck

Comment: Well, I understand WordPress handles a lot of plugins, so can you recommend me somehow look for a puglin that allows me to improve the performance of the page load?

thanks for commenting tshimkus

Comment: Run it through https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/. It will break down areas for improvement and recommend specific plugins to help speed the site up

Comment: Thank you very much tshimkus, I will reassess that page well to see what else I can help improve.